# Which is faster, where statement or where data set option

Tags: sas

The question is really straight forward, which one is faster?

Considering we are using data step with two datasets in the set statement and the datasets have the same variables in them.

From What Ive heard and read, if we subset them using the same condition, say date = "10jan2014"d, the result will be exactly the same using the statement above or the following data set option in the two datasets (where=(date="10jan2014"d)). Because the where is executed before anything comes to the PDV.

Is that right?

For better understanding of the question, I created the following code:

Lets say we have these two datasets.

```
data people1;
format birth date9.;
input name $ birth :date9.;
datalines;
John 18jan1980
Mary 20feb1980
;
run;

data people2;
format birth date9.;
input name $ birth :date9.;
datalines;
Peter 18mar1980
Judas 18jan1980
;
run;
```

I want to create a new dataset with those two, but only for people with birth date equals to 18jan1980.
Now I can use the where statement or the where data set option.

Using the where (data set option):

```
data everybody1;
set people1 (where=(birth="18jan1980"d))
    people2 (where=(birth="18jan1980"d));
run;
```

Using the where statement:

```
data everybody2;
set people1
    people2;
where birth="18jan1980"d;
run;
```

The new datasets now have the exact same output. But whith one is faster?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why it received a downvote.  Seemed like a valuable and answerable question to me.

Comment: Very likely because it was in the New Posts or whatever queue and someone who doesn't understand SAS doesn't understand the question.  I've seen this a lot.

Comment: Now, I would suggest improving the post by having two in-code-block examples and an example input dataset, showing exactly what you're asking if they are equivalent.

Comment: Will do Joe. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are identical in terms of performance.  And yes, the where will only allow matching results to be loaded to the PDV.

According to the documentation (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202951.htm):

> The WHERE statement selects observations before they are brought into
>   the program data vector, making it a more efficient programming
>   technique.

The above quote is talking about `where` vs `if` statements but it does confirm that `where` clauses don't bring the data into the PDV.

EDIT : Thanks to Joe's link, I'm going to provide a quote a better excerpt from the docs (http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p04fy20d8il3nfn1ssywe4f25k27.htm):

> You can use a WHERE expression in both a DATA step and SAS procedures,
>   as well as in a windowing environment, SCL programs, and as a data set
>   option. A WHERE expression tests the condition before an observation
>   is read into the PDV. If the condition is true, the observation is
>   read into the PDV and processed. If the condition is false, the
>   observation is not read into the PDV, and processing continues with
>   the next observation. This can yield substantial savings when
>   observations contain many variables or very long character variables
>   (up to 32K bytes).

Comment: On second thoughts, I'm not 100% sure on the PDV part.  I might have to research that a little more.

Comment: I was reading this page yesterday trying to confirm it, I understood, but when I was told I was wrong, I doubted myself, I thought maybe I got it all wrong. Thanks again. I will upvote this as soon as I get the rep.

Comment: `where` definitely doesn't bring in observations that fail it.  Obviously it has to read the observation to some effect, unless there is an `index` (in which case it can entirely skip the observation!), but it doesn't ever bring it into the PDV.

Comment: @RobertPenridge - look at the [Where Expression](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1jd70cudhsnogn1d6kr8j43n6bu.htm) concept (also linked in my answer) - in particular the "If vs Where" - it's very explicit about the PDV and uses almost exactly the same language.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the `where` statement and the `where` data set option is how they take effect: the former affects all input datasets that do not have a `where` dataset option, and the latter affects only the dataset that it is an option on (and overrides the `where` statement).

See the documentation for the [where data set option](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000131192.htm) and the [where statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202951.htm) for more information, as well as the [Where Expression Processing](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1jd70cudhsnogn1d6kr8j43n6bu.htm) concept.  In particular, the latter does not differentiate between the two kinds of `where` expression in terms of performance; it only specifies the difference in terms of how they take effect.

Answer (score 0):

For reference,

I actually checked the difference of cpu time and I/O usage for

```
Keep/Drop
```

Statement at data step with set statement and not with set statement.

And the result is if not with set statement, the CPU time and I/ o Usage is less than the case with set statement, in particular with 1/2 smaller in I/ O usage.

And with keep/ drop statements appearing at both set option and data step, the CPU time is further reduced with I/O equals above observation.

This might be helpful given that keep / drop statements are compile-time statsments too.

Comment: He's asking about the `where` dataset option versus the `where` statement, not about location in the data step.

Comment: Thanks, i think i always have problems in understanding questions.

Comment: That's okay - feel free to ask questions in the comments if you're unsure.